# Return redirect with variable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I have this code inside a function :

```
 today = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=0)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
 quicklink_t = f"?start_date={today}&end_date={today}"
 w_today = quicklink_t
 return redirect('workspace-detail', token=workspace.token)
```

But I want to add the variable **w_today** at the end of my redirect link to specify some parameters.

How could I achieve that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the strings `workspace-detail` and `w_today` respectively:

```
return redirect('workspace-detail' + w_today, token=workspace.token)
```